# MS Access 2016. Error Code "2501".RunSQL was cancelled

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

When I tried to generate the report
The error code"2501" pop out.
I seems like something wrong occur between this code

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong.
Thank you.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL ("update 統計資料 set 狗 = " + Format(a) + " where 狀況 = 'B/F'")
```

Comment: `Format` needs 2 parameters.

Comment: Is this vb.net of VBA?